# my resnet32, vgg16,vgg19, densenet do not converge

Tags: caffe, digits

I have an interesting problem. I am working on a project which I am trying to classify 15 logos (14 logo + 1 nonlogo class). The dataset is our own. I am using Digits 5 /6 that employs caffe. My caffe is 0.15.14 flavored by NVIDIA.

I have trained it with Alexnet and Googlenet which have been shipped with Digits. The models built by from scratch and finetuning seem ok. (GLT: 90% accuracy, alexnet: 80%) Meanwhile, these models have been created by finetuning the pretrained models (IMAGENET)

My problem is, I wanted to extend my study to cover resnet 32, densenet 121 and vgg16-19. Whenever I try to model these models, their top 1 accuracies get very poor results. (Generally 0) You might guess (as I did) that sources from by building from scratch. However, as far as i know, the model should converge to some limit but i always see a straight line after 2,3 epochs (the line is accuracy line and it is generally 0) the loss value increases to 87 after a few epochs.

I have searched the possible reasons that i may encounter.
1. I changed the weight_filler param to "xavier" nothing has changed.
2. I increased the learning rate but nothing has changed.
3. I even used a pretrained model to finetune vgg16 but it is still the same.
4. I used the cifar10 dataset by upscaling the image sizes to 224*224 and tried but the values are very similar to my logo dataset

I am struggling in finding the correct way. I am not an expert but it seems soo odd to me to have such bad results after having nice ones in alexnet and googlenet.

Why my models do not converge on these recent networks. I need your advices.

btw my training data contains 400 images per class and for non logo class i have collected 1200 non logo images. The validation data contains different numbers of images per logo class and a different 1200 non logo images for validation. So I have totally 5204 training, 579 test(10% of training) and 4729 validation images

Here i am attaching a trainval.txt for my resnet 32 model. 
So what is my problem?

Thanks in advance

---

[resnet32_train_val.prototxt](https://docs.google.com/document/d/15b6czZw-CM9akhCvoqxgAA1sFIYZfqT5Bx26i3CHB8M/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: have you tried **decreasing** the learning rate? use `debug_info: true` in soler prototxt and see what happens to the gradients

Comment: Thank you very much. I have decreased it and it worked for me. However, I have a bit interesting accuracy scores on my data such as:

1) googlenet: 87%
2) resnet 101: 75%
3) resnet 50: 70%

these are top-1 scores. I noticed that decreasing the lr gives better results during the finetuning. Nonetheless, the scores above are a bit weird to me since resnet is much more deeper and proved to be better than googlenet (inception1) on imagenet. Can inception1 work better than resnet architectures? Is this normal or should I play with lr again?

Comment: There is a lot you can gain from tweaking the meta-parameters. Try decreasing the LR even more. Try `"Adam"` solver. Try...

Comment: Hello again. I have tested the parameters a lot by making more than 30 models. The performance gets higher as you mentioned. However, I could not figure out why resnet50 achieves much worse than inceptionv1. I selected different hyperparameters but does not make sense. Theory says that, resnet50 is much deeper and infers better than inception1. But my practice is different. What do say about this finding?